# Regex to match middle name/s

Tags: regex, import.io

Assume input of a string containing a full name. Full names are very diverse - ie. Joe Bloggs, Joe Bloggs-Phillips, Joe Bloggs Phillips, Joe Bloggs Adams Phillips, Joe van den Bloggs, Joe van-der Bloggs.

I want to match what I will call "middle names". That is everything between the first and last space. That is, as above - "Bloggs Adams", "van den" and "van-der". Names with hyphenated words are full surnames. What is the regex for this?

PS. I'm aware of the cultural diversity in names, eg. "van der" is not actually  a middle name but the start of a surname. So, if there is logic to build in to this regex to accommodate, this would help. Otherwise, I want to assume:

- First name - everything up to first space.
- Middle name - from first space to last space.
- Last name - from final space to end.

Many thanks.

Comment: have you tried anything yet? that'll also show us what language you are talking about

Comment: import.io, a web data-scraping application. No language. import.io supports one use of regex on fields, so it's one regex required with no language processing.

Comment: You need to specify what language do you use, as regex flavors vary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
^(\S+)\s+(.*\b)\s+(\S+)$
```

The first capture group is the first name, second group is the middle name, third group is the last name.

Comment: I only want the middle name. This seems to give first only. I don't fully understand.

Comment: `second group is the middle name` - @RobertAndrews try reading the answer =).

Comment: I read the answer. Which are you taking to be the second group?     \s+(.*\b) ? That doesn't return middle name for me. But, like I said, I don't fully understand.

Comment: The regex in the question will return "foo (this bit. whatever it is) bar" in the second capturing group. If it doesn't work - try showing what you're doing and in what way it doesn't work. It's a pretty trivial regex/question - so it's easy to say/see that it should work. If your problem is that import.io only expects one capturing group or something _say so_.

Comment: @RobertAndrews You haven't said what programming language you're using. In PHP, you would use `$match[2]` to get the second capturing group (replace `$match` with the variable you give as the 3rd argument to `preg_match`.

Comment: @Barmar - no programming language. I mentioned import.io, a web scraping graphical application. I'm just talking about a single regex, no processing.

Comment: @AD7six - on "Paulina Pastor Alfonso", your `^(\S+)\s+(.*\b)\s+(\S+)$` returns "Paulina". I want "Pastor".

Comment: "your" ? But anyway [no it doesn't](http://i.stack.imgur.com/49Qbd.png), you can use none-capturing groups (as shown in the screenshot) to prevent capturing/returning groups you don't care about. Your problem is import.io. The answer to "what language are you using" is effectively: import.io - you should be asking their support your question, or reading their docs, because the regex to do what you ask is on this page already.

Comment: I just took a quick glance at import.io, it looks like they provide an API, which you use from some programming language like PHP. It's in that language that you would use the regexp to extract the parts you want.

Comment: This regex doesnt work on people with no middle names, FYI.